# is it possible to scan a LAN for localhosts?

Tags: android, networking, network-programming

I am a technician and travel to customers all the time. At site i need to connect to a localhost webpage located on a server somewhere in the network. I dont always have the IPadress and the premises is big. I wish there was a way to scan the network for localhost. I'm of course connected to wifi.

I have created a tool on my android device that finds the local iPadress and connects to the localhost with the most know ipadress of my customers. But sometimes not all network configuration is standard, so it can be difficult to find the last numbers in the iPadress.

So my question is: is it possible to scan a network (lan) for localhost pages?
Is it a know way or tool to do this with windows or android?

Comment: You probably want to reword your question. The term "localhost" means the host itself, not a different host. The loopback address is what is assigned to the localhost, and traffic with that address can never be seen on a network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Fing Network Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing&hl=en) Android application. It's great for spidering a LAN to discover connected devices and identify them. Once the discovery is complete you can run a port/service scan for HTTP servers to find your "localhost" site.